# Code making folders gives error on empty cell value

Tags: vba, directory

I have designed a code for creating a folder based on cell value but in that excel spreadsheet contains formula. if the cell value empty at that time stop the process kindly help.

```
Sub MakeFolders()

    Dim xdir As String
    Dim FSO
    Dim lstrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    lstrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To lstrow
        'change the path on the next line where you want to create the folders
        xdir = Range("E" & i).Value & Range("B" & i).Value
        If Not FSO.FolderExists(xdir) Then
               FSO.CreateFolder (xdir)
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Folder Created Successfully", vbInformation, "Info"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: On which line does the code break?

Comment: If your problem is that when `xdir` is empty gives error, put the code creating the folder inside an If statement `If Not xdir = vbNullString`

Comment: Have you checked if the content of `xdir` is what you expect? Not a missing Backslash character?

Comment: @MrML it breaks on     FSO.CreateFolder (xdir)

Comment: @Damian can u help me where should i insert id statement?

Comment: @FunThomas Yes xdir showing empty but at that time it show error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should bypass your error:

```
Sub MakeFolders()
    Dim xdir As String
    Dim FSO
    Dim lstrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    lstrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To lstrow
        'change the path on the next line where you want to create the folders
        xdir = Range("E" & i).Value & Range("B" & i).Value
        If Not xdir = vbNullString And Not FSO.FolderExists(xdir) Then 'I've added here a check for the xdir value, if it's empty it won't try to create the folder.
            FSO.CreateFolder (xdir)
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Folder Created Successfully", vbInformation, "Info"

End Sub
```